# Evaluating expression from abstract syntax tree

Tags: c, abstract-syntax-tree, rpn

I have an abstract syntax tree that I made from a reverse polish notation expression. The tree's nodes are all strings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct snode 
{
  char *datum;
  struct snode* bottom;
};

struct tnode
{
  char *datum;
  struct tnode* left;
  struct tnode*right;
};

struct snode* 
push(struct snode* stack, char *x) {
  struct snode *S = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
  S->datum = (char *)malloc(strlen(x) + 1);
  strcpy(S->datum, x);
  S->bottom = stack;
  return S;
}

void
pop(struct snode **stack) {
  struct snode *S;
  if (*stack == NULL)
    return;

  S = (*stack)->bottom;
  free(*stack);
  *stack = S;
}

char *
peek(struct snode* stack){
  return stack->datum;
}


struct tnode*
create_node(char *x){
  struct tnode* tmp = (struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
  tmp->datum = (char *)malloc(strlen(x) + 1);
  strcpy(tmp->datum, x);
  tmp->right = NULL;
  tmp->left = NULL;
  return tmp;
}

void
print_table(struct tnode *AST){
  if(AST !=NULL){
    printf("(");
    print_table(AST->left);
    printf("%s", AST->datum);
    print_table(AST->right);
    printf(")");
  }
}

int
is_operator(char *tok)
{
  return !strcmp(tok, "A") || !strcmp(tok, "S") || !strcmp(tok, "X") || !strcmp(tok, "D") || !strcmp(tok, "M");
}


struct tnode*
build_tree(struct snode **S)
{

  struct tnode* root;
  if (*S == NULL)
    return NULL;

  char *top = peek(*S);

  if (is_operator(top))
    {
      root = create_node(top);
      pop(S); 
      root->right = build_tree(S);
      pop(S);
      root->left = build_tree(S);
      return root;
    } 

  root = create_node(top);

  return root;
}


int
isoperator(struct tnode *AST)
{
  return !strcmp(AST->datum, "A") || !strcmp(AST->datum, "S") || !strcmp(AST->datum, "X") || !strcmp(AST->datum, "D") || !strcmp(AST->datum, "M");
}


int
main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{

  int i = 1;
  struct tnode *tree = NULL;
  struct snode *stack = NULL;

  char *value;
  while (argv[i]!= NULL)
    {
      value = argv[i];
      stack = push(stack, value);
      i++;
    }


  tree =  build_tree(&stack);
  print_table(tree);
  printf("\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the code I have so far. For the evaluate function, I have thought about using this:

```
int evaluate( struct tnode* AST )
{
  int x, y, z;
  if ( AST != NULL ){
    if (isoperator(AST->datum)){
          x = evaluate( AST->left);
          y = evaluate( AST->right );
          switch ( AST->datum )
            {
            case 'A':
              z = x + y;
              break;
            case 'S':
              z = x - y;
              break;
            case 'X':
              z = x * y;
              break;
            case 'D':
              z = x / y;
              break;
            case 'M':
              z = x % y;
              break;
            }
          return z;
        }

    return AST->datum;
  }
}
```

but I don't think this will work because I'm using strings instead of ints. what can I change on my evaluate function?

EDIT: I've noticed the code I posted was a little messy. I've cleaned it up so it looks a little better.

EDIT2:

```
int evaluate( struct tnode* AST )
{
  int x, y, z;
  if ( AST != NULL ){
    if (isoperator(AST->datum)){
      x = evaluate( AST->left);
      y = evaluate( AST->right );
      if(strcmp(AST->datum,"A")==0){
        z = x + y;
      }else if(strcmp(AST->datum,"S")==0){
        z = x -  y;
      }else if(strcmp(AST->datum,"X")==0){
        z = x * y;
      }else if(strcmp(AST->datum,"D")==0){
        z = x / y;
      }else if(strcmp(AST->datum,"M")==0){
        z = x % y;
      }
      return z;
     }
    return atoi(AST->datum);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried getting rid of the switch statement but I am now getting a core dump. This is just something I wanted to try. I would prefer fixing my previous evaluate function

Comment: You can do `char c = 'A'; int ix = c - 'A'`. Or simply `c + 0` if you don't mind that the numbering doesn't start at 0.

Comment: Please don't use the "code snippet" button for C code. It is only for runnable web stuff (html/JS). Use the normal code button `{}`.

Comment: It looks like you only have numbers and operators. So in case your current node is no operator, simply returning `atoi(AST->datum)` should do the job (assuming that `AST->datum` is zero-terminated). Another thing: The code for operator `'S'` (= subtract?) of function `evaluate` looks incorrect...

Comment: I had trouble copying and pasting from Unix but everthing should be fixed. So at the end of the 'evaluate' function I should change 'return AST->datum' to 'return atoi(AST->datum);' ? @LukasThomsen

Comment: Why are you using a tree? A stack will do. There are lots of algorithms to do this. I wrote it in 6502A assembly

Comment: I have multiple operations I have to perform on the expression and my instructor told me that the easiest way to perform these operations would be  by a tree instead of a stack. @EdHeal

Comment: Your instructor is wrong. Look up the algorithms for converting infix to postfix and its evaluation.

Comment: I think that's kind of rude to say. We had a previous lab assignment where we only used the stack. But like I said, we have multiple operations we have to perform on the expression and this method should make them easier. @EdHeal

Comment: I made that change but I am getting an error that says 'error: switch quantity not an integer'. any suggestions on how to fix this? @LukasThomsen

Comment: @etorr96 - The shunning algorithm is good for any expression, easy to implement and good for memory usage.

Comment: Even if it is easier, this assignment was given to us again for a reason and as a student trying to learn, I'd like to practice with every possible solution. thank you for your input though. @EdHeal

Comment: I would have thought that your tutor would be proud that you have done research over the matter. For the record you do not need the casts on malloc return values

Comment: @etorr96: This error is not caused by the modification but the `switch ( AST->datum )` which is not an integer but an `char *`. An ugly fix for that would be `switch (AST->datum[0] )` but this assumes that the operator is always the first character of your tokens. Better build several if checks using `strcmp` as within your `isoperator` function.

Comment: what kind of checks? @LukasThomsen

Comment: @LukasThomsen One would think that `isoperator(x)` would guarantee that `switch (AST->datum[0])` is valid since the only operators are represented as single-character strings. Perhaps I miss the point of the reason behind mentioning the ugly fix.

Comment: @etorr96 You should `return 0;` in the event that `ast->left` or `ast->right` is NULL. Aside from that, where is your `else { ... }` for non-operators? If you need help with converting a string to an integer, a good start would be [the `strtol()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: I have made this change with the 'return 0;'.  I have also edited the post to something new I've tried. What is the difference between strol() and atoi? @ChronoKitsune

Comment: @etorr96 The difference between `strtol()` and `atoi()` is simple: what if the "number" isn't actually a number? That is, what if you end up with `"ABC" "A" "9"`? With `strtol()`, you can at least check for errors in two ways: 1) `errno` will be unset, and 2) the object to which the second argument of `strtol()` points will be a string. With `atoi()`, you cannot necessarily do that. See [the difference between `strtol()` and `atoi()`](http://ideone.com/aarpnh).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have sufficient reputation to comment so I will put an error that I noticed, the coredump is probably from this error.

Your isoperator function needs a pointer to struct tnode

```
int isoperator(struct tnode *AST);
```

But you give it AST->datum which is a char * in your evaluate function:

```
if (isoperator(AST->datum))
```

If you correcte you condition to this :

```
if (isoperator(AST))
```

It will probably works better.